# Drupal multi-language redirection

Tags: drupal, multilingual

I am developing a Drupal 7 site with multi-language, using only locales module. Two questions.

1.I made a custom "forgot my password" page, accessible through http://example.com/fr/user/password for french. Once I enter my email and click the button, it get redirected to /user, loosing the language on the way.

I wrote my own submit handler and redirect to another page without much success. It looks like on the submit, the form is rebuild, without the language in the url, and from that point on, everything is happening in the default language. How can I keep the language reference ?

2.Drupal core messages are not translated, like "Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.", even if its under the t().

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Losing the language may be because of how you have your detection set up. Language detection settings are at 'admin/config/regional/language/configure'. But it may also be because you are redirecting to the wrong language? How are you getting the url to redirect to?
You should use the [l() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) or [url() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) as I think these will respect the current language and give you the correct url.

You should be able to translate messages on the translate interface at: admin/config/regional/translate/translate